# Using multiple Contains taking time to load performance issue in Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have more than 600,000 records and 20 columns in a table.

I would like to use a LINQ query and use a function that works as a "LIKE"; So for that I used `Contains`. It's taking time (or) it throws a timeout expired exception.

So can anyone suggest how to solve this issue? I need to compare more than 4 columns.

```
var majorAgents = new[] { "iPhone", "Android", "iPad" };


List<Person> lstperson =_context.person.where 
                      (w=>majorAgents.Any(x=>w.personLastName.contains(x))
                      || majorAgents.Any(x=>w.personFirstName.contains(x))
                      ||w.Address.Any(s=>majorAgents.Contains(s.addressProof)))//Address table referenced as a list 
                        .select(s=> new Person{
                             s.personId,
                             s.perosnLastName,
                             s.personFirstName
                    }).ToList();
```

Comment: I would suggest to select the entire data from table and perform contains over there. It might be faster. Also, try to check this by writing a SQL stored procedure and calling it from EF(I believe you are using it)

Comment: If performance is very important maybe you could have another column with the value you're looking for pre-calculated.

Comment: AFAIK there is performance issue to use `OR` in a SQL query, I can suggest to remove those `||` like: `where(w=>majorAgents.Any(x=>$"{w.personLastName}|@|{w.personFirstName}".contains(x)))` ;).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try to run the `majorAgents.Any` query only once for all the properties having a possibility. In order to do so, you can try concatenating the `firstName`, `lastName` and `addressProof` fields and checking if the `majorAgent` string is present in this concatenated string anywhere.

**Note**: I have intentionally modified the `Address` related condition as it seems to be irrelevant to the task at hand. In original query, it says: `w.Address.Any(s=>majorAgents.Contains(s.addressProof)` which means 'check in majorAgents if there is any addressProof' whereas it would be more sensible to check if `addressProof of any Address has any of the majorAgents`. For that I have used `w.Address.SelectMany(a => a.addressProof).ToArray()` along with `string.Join` which will give me space separated addressProof strings in which I can look for any majorAgent. In case this is not what is intended, please modify that part of address as it suits the requirement.

So, the modified query to try is:

```
var majorAgents = new[] { "iPhone", "Android", "iPad" };


List<Person> lstperson =_context.person.where 
                      (w=>majorAgents.Any(x=>(w.personLastName + " " + w.personFirstName + " " +string.Join(" ",w.Address.SelectMany(a => a.addressProof).ToArray())).contains(x))
                      )
                        .select(s=> new Person{
                             s.personId,
                             s.perosnLastName,
                             s.personFirstName
                    }).ToList();
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: We don't use  string concatenation in server side so without using string concatenation can we handle the performance issue .

Comment: Using ToArray() it will takes time to get the values. Actually it won't improve the performance.

Answer (score -1):

Doing contains will be more performatic than making a 'any'.
Take the following test:

```
var majorAgents = new[] { "iPhone", "Android", "iPad" };

List<Person> lstperson=_context.person.where 
     (c=> majorAgents.contains(c.personLastName) || majorAgents.contains(c.personFirstName))
    .select(s=> new Person{
             s.PersonId,
             s.perosnLastName,
             s.personFirstName
}).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks @jonathan ,removing of any its slightly fast but i need to improve performance more...

Comment: if i used another table i merged in Linq using Any()

>List<Person> lstperson=_context.person.where 
     (c=> majorAgents.contains(c.personLastName) || majorAgents.contains(c.personFirstName) && Address.Any(majorAgents.contains(c.addressProof)))
    .select(s=> new Person{
             s.PersonId,
             s.perosnLastName,
             s.personFirstName
}).ToList();

Comment: the original query and this query do different things.  The one in the question will check if the majorAgents are contained in the personLastName.  This checks if the personLastName is contained in the majorAgents array.

Comment: @JohnBoker is correct, the modified contain query isn't the same as the original Any query